# How to output a PDF buffer to browser using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf, buffer

So I am using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to convert my html and here is my code:

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf')
var html = 'somehtmlfile.html'

pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(buffer)
          var pdfBuffer = new Buffer(buffer)
          res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="test.pdf"');
          res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
          res.send(pdfBuffer)
        }
}
```

I am not getting any PDF file to be downloader nor any output of a pdf file in the browser. The `console.log(buffer)` is this:

```
<Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 0a 2f 54 69 74 6c 65 20 28 fe ff 29 0a 2f 43 72 65 61 74 6f 72 20 28 fe ff 29 0a 2f 50 72 6f ... >
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? Or am I doing it wrong?

I just want to output the buffer in a pdf form in the browser.

Comment: Which lib is this that you are using to create the PDF (pdf.create)?

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy uhm I just said it in the post

Answer (score 6):

Change to:

```
pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        res.set('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
        stream.pipe(res)
    }
});
```

Comment: Success, but nothing happens

Comment: Nothing happens where?  Which http framework are you using that gives you `res`?

Comment: I am using express

Comment: Tell me what you mean by "nothing happens". What is expected and what happened? And a note, if you want to send to the client a file to be downloaded, not to be shown as a content, got with `res.download` (https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)

Comment: I am using express and I am not getting any errors. The code was successful but there's no pdf output in the browser

Comment: Check again my answer. I changed `res.setHeader` to `res.set` and threw away `Content-disposition` as it is not needed if is not a case for download.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139392/discussion-between-fewflyby-and-diego-zoracky).

Comment: If you want to download the file in the browser try this: `res.contentType('application/pdf')
res.attachment()
stream.pipe(res)`

Answer (score 1):

> you can use the below function or `html.create(somehtmlfile.html).toStream()`

*function to convert a buffer to stream*

```
 function bufferToStream(buffer) {  
     let stream = new Duplex();
     stream.push(buffer);
     stream.push(null);
     return stream;
   }
```

*download or view a pdf in browser if it's a stream*

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf')
var html = 'somehtmlfile.html'
exports.generatePdf = (req, res) =>{
    pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else {
              console.log(buffer)

           bufferToStream(buffer).pipe(res)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(buffer)
        res.header('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
        res.send(buffer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to make this process asynchronous? I am generating an S3 link inside the callback but it does not wait for link

Answer (score 1):

```
function bufferToStream(buffer) {
          let stream = new Duplex();
          stream.push(buffer);
          stream.push(null);
          return stream;
        }

        pdf.create(doctoPdf).toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log("buffer");
            console.log(buffer)
            res.contentType('application/pdf')
            res.attachment()
            return bufferToStream(buffer).pipe(res)

          }
        })
```

> if you want to download it on the client-side then this will be help full.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in client side:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    console.log(oReq.response);
    var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "application/pdf"});
    var win = window.open('', '_blank');
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    win.location = dataUrl;
};
oReq.send();
```

In server Side:

```
pdf.create(htmlContent).toStream(function(err, stream){
    console.log("in post method"+stream.length);
        res.header('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

        stream.pipe(res);
});
```